# How to make Text fill the width in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a GridView with 2 columns and the grid items in the following way

1. Image as background (which would be downloaded from internet)
2. Name of the item to be shown on the bottom of the card with transparent black background.

I tried the following way

```
Container(
  color: Colors.redAccent,
  child: GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 4,
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Image.network(
                  "http://localhost:1337${products[index].thumb_image?.url ?? ""}",
                  errorBuilder: (context, error, url) =>
                      Icon(Icons.image_outlined),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: double.infinity,
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    "Value = $index",
                    style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.black26),
                  ),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              ),
            ],
          ),              
        );
      }),
)
```

[image: Screenshot of the error I am receiving]

But, the text is not filling the complete card. How can I make the `Text` match the width?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Align(
           child: Text("Value = $index",
                       style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.black)),
           alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

use `FittedBox` widget

```
Container(
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  child: FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  child: Text("Text"),
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
          Align(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Text(
                "Value = $index",
                style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.black26),
              ),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
```